# NuGet add reference error while installing package

Tags: windows-phone-8, nuget-package

I am not able to install any package by Nuget.

```
Install-Package MyToolkit.Extended

Attempting to resolve dependency 'MyToolkit (≥ 2.2.3.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async (≥ 1.0.166)'.
Install-Package : The 'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.168' package requires NuGet clint version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet 
version is '2.7.40911.287'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package MyToolkit.Extended
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],       NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId :    NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the error message you got, I'd suggest to check and update your NuGet Visual Studio Extension (Tools > Extenstions and Update) before installing the library package.

Note: Restart visual studio after updating Nuget VS extension and before downloading your library package.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this problem. Even if the system Nuget is updated, the NuGet.exe in the .nuget directory could be older.  Adding/removing the extension and playing around inside VS does not seem to update the NuGet.exe inside the solution. Even when you explicitly update Nuget inside VS, the solution's copy stays old.

Go into the .nuget folder and do "`NuGet update -self`".

Comment: Update - migrate to the newer version of Nuget package restore. See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27410376/492

Answer (score 1):

from Tools>Extnensions And Updates> uninstall NuGet and install in again, hope it will solve your problem